# Question regarding least value of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The question regarding which i am asking this question is as follows

Prove that that least positive value of $x$, satisfying $\tan(x) = x+1$, lies in the interval $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2})$

The solution to this question in my text book is done using a graph, however this method becomes infeasible for more complex equations.

Is their any other way to solve this maybe analytically, using derivatives or something, anything i tried seemed to fail could someone please help me with this one.

Is their a analytical we to find the smallest intersection of 2 functions?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is very hard to answer this without knowing the level you are operating at. I would look at $f(x)=\tan x - x-1$ and notice that $f(0)=-1, f(\pi/4)=-\pi/4$ and $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to\pi/2-$; and that $f'(x)=\sec^2 x-1>0$. That will tell you that there is no zero in $(0,\pi/4)$ and at least one zero in $(\pi/4,\pi/2$. But you need something like to Intermediate Value Theorem to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ we have $$\tan(x)<1\leq x+1$$

and $\tan(\pi/4)=1\neq \pi/4+1$ so the first intersection must happen after $\pi/4$.

Now we just need to prove there is an intersection in $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$.

For this, define $g(x)=\tan(x)-x-1$.

We have $g(\pi/4)=-\pi/4<0$.

Moreover, as $$\lim_{x\to\pi/{2}^-} \tan(x)=+\infty $$

and $$\lim_{x\to\pi/{2}^-} -x-1=-\pi/2-1$$

we have $$\lim_{x\to\pi/{2}^-} g(x)=+\infty$$

Therefore, there exists some $y\in (\pi/4,\pi/2)$ such that $g(y)>0$.

As $g$ is continuous and $g(\pi/4)<0, g(y)>0$ by the IVT there exists some $c\in(\pi/4,y)$ such that $g(c)=0$, that is, $\tan(c)=c+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!